# Error when adding textfields to HTML form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, uitextfield

I'm building a mobile web service which allow employees to enter worked hours on their phone. I have created a form that is constructed by a php loop function, which loops an array of all the days in a week. That works perfectly fine, the form looks like this:

[image]

Now, as you can see, each day has a + button. I want to make that users can add textfields by tapping this button. In each textfield they can then add a description of tasks done while working.

This is the code I want to use for this:

```
<input id="<? echo $i;?>" type="button" class="plusButton" onclick="addField(<?echo $i; ?>);"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function addField(p) {


                var newField = document.createElement("input");
                newField.type = 'text';
                newField.width = '50px';
                newField.height = '20px';

                var weekDays = new Array();

                <?

                for($q = 0; $q < count($weekDays); $q++) { ?>
                    weekDays.push(<? echo $weekDays[$q]; ?>);
                <? } ?>

                document.getElementById(weekDays[p]).innerHTML.appendChild(newField);
                alert(weekDays[p]);
            }
        </script>
```

not that `$weekDays` is a php array, containing Monday until Sunday (in Dutch).

**The problem:**
For some reason I keep on getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(weekDays[p]).innerHTML')
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong and I am trying and looking on the internet for more than a day to solve this. Any help in solving this issue would be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to replace:

```
document.getElementById(weekDays[p]).innerHTML.appendChild(newField);
```

With:

```
document.getElementById(weekDays[p]).appendChild(newField);
```

`Element.innerHTML` returns a String. You can't call `appendChild` on a string.

Comment: It also seems like `document.getElementById(weekDays[p])` returns null. Make sure `p` and `weekdays[p]` aren't undefined, and that the `getElementById` actually returns the desired element.

Comment: it indeed seems to get a null object, But i am defining all the objects properly. I already tried taking this code out of the loop but that is also not the issue.

Comment: okay I fixed it already, I had to do `weekDays.push('<? echo $weekDays[$q]; ?>');` instead of `weekDays.push(<? echo $weekDays[$q]; ?>);` thanks anyway!